# Boolean method that returns an int value;

Tags: java, boolean, return

I am teaching myself Java, and I created a program to simulate a game of craps. I have the entire game in a Boolean method. Everything works fine, but I want to count every time the user wins. What is the best way to count these wins, and then print them?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class game{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        craps(rand);
    }
}

public static boolean craps(Random randomGen){
    int roll1 = randomGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int roll2 = randomGen.nextInt(6) + 1;

    int sum = roll1 + roll2;
    int sumRepeat = sum;
    int count = 0;


    String win = "you win";
    String lose = "you lose";
    String point = "point=";

    if(sum == 7 || sum == 11){
        System.out.printf("[%d,%d] %d %s\n",roll1,roll2,sum,win);
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    else if(sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12){
        System.out.printf("[%d,%d] %d %s\n",roll1,roll2,sum,lose);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        System.out.printf("[%d,%d] %s %d",roll1,roll2,point,sum);
        int roll3 = randomGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int roll4 = randomGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int sum2 = roll3 + roll4;
        do{
            roll3 = randomGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
            roll4 = randomGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
            sum2 = roll3 + roll4;
            if(sum2 == sumRepeat){
                System.out.printf("[%d,%d] %d %s\n",roll3,roll4,sum2,win);
                count++;
                return true;
            }else{
                System.out.printf("[%d,%d]",roll3,roll4);
            }
        }
        while(sum2 != 7);{
            System.out.printf("[%d,%d] %d %s\n",roll3,roll4,sum2,lose);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have tried to return the count variable but I get an error saying I can't return an int value from a Boolean method which I expected. But I also tried to print out the count value with `System.out.println();` But I can't find a place in the code to put it since I always get an error stating that the println is unreachable code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Here is the output of the program**

> [1,6] 7 you win
>
> [2,4] point= 6[3,6][3,3] 6 you win
>
> [3,3] point= 6[5,1] 6 you win
>
> [6,1] 7 you win
>
> [6,3] point= 9[5,1][3,5][2,6][6,4][5,6][1,5][6,3] 9 you win
>
> [3,3] point= 6[1,5] 6 you win
>
> [5,1] point= 6[1,5] 6 you win
>
> [2,2] point= 4[6,4][3,3][3,4][3,4] 7 you lose
>
> [4,5] point= 9[6,4][5,1][1,2][6,2][1,5][3,5][6,5][1,5][5,2][5,2] 7 you lose
>
> [2,2] point= 4[5,3][5,6][6,4][3,2][6,5][3,6][4,4][4,2][4,3][4,3] 7 you lose
>
> [6,6] 12 you lose
>
> You won 11 time(s).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Count them outside the `craps` function, here's one simple way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        if(craps(rand)) counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("You won " + counter + " times!");
}
```

By the way, it's important to note that it's far superior to count outside the `craps` function than it is to modify it. As you learn java, remember that each method should only do one job. You may want to practice breaking the `craps` function into smaller pieces to practice this philosophy. The *one method to one job* philosophy will make larger projects much easier to understand and debug when you are looking back later.

Comment: I implemented your solution, and it almost works like I wanted. The only problem Is it's counting every time a game is played. Instead of counting everytime the user wins a round. I will paste a copy of the output of my program to make everything clearer. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you copy-pasted exactly, it should work... unless your `craps` function always returns `true`. I didn't actually check that function, I just assumed it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
int wins = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    if(craps(rand)) {
        wins++;
    }
}

// Print a friendly message including `wins`
```